# Trying to create child objects for each value of a multi-value field

Tags: apex

I have a list ('names') which is being created by a VF page which contains the Names of other records. I am attempting to create a new child record (object : Product_Affected_Entry__c) for each of the entries in that list. That is working properly.

However, I am also attempting to query each record which those entries represents and place the recordID into the Vendor_Product__c field of the child record I am creating - and that field is only being populated in the first child record created.

I believe the problem may be in this portion of the trigger :

```
// get the ids for all vendor products and store in a map keyed by name
           Map<String, Id> subAccIdsByName=new Map<String, Id>();

           for (Vendor_Product__c subAcc : [select id, Name from Vendor_Product__c where Name in :subAccNames]) 
                   {
                      subAccIdsByName.put(subAcc.Name, subAcc.id);
System.debug('subAcc Name and ID=' + subAcc.Name +'Id=' + subAcc.id);
                   }

System.debug('subAccIdsByName=' + subAccIdsByName);
```

The subAccIdsName debug is producing :

```
subAccIdsByName={Red=a7v5600000000O3AAI}
```

Here is the full trigger :

```
trigger AutoCreateSubsServOnContrOv on Policy_Profile__c (After insert, after update) 
        {
           List<Product_Affected_Entry__c> subs = new List<Product_Affected_Entry__c>();

           // get the full list of sub account names for all records being processed by the trigger

           List<String> subAccNames=new List<String>();

           for (Policy_Profile__c newCont : Trigger.New) 
           {
              if (newCont.Products_Affected3__c != '[]') 
              {
                 // split out the multi-select picklist using a comma delimiter
System.debug('Products_Affected3__c ' + newCont.Products_Affected3__c);

                 String temp = newCont.Products_Affected3__c;
                 temp = temp.replace(']','');
                 temp = temp.replace('[','');
                 String[] all = temp.split(',');
                 subAccNames.addAll(all);
                 for (String acctName : all) 
System.debug('acctname ' + acctName);
              }
           }

           // get the ids for all vendor products and store in a map keyed by name
           Map<String, Id> subAccIdsByName=new Map<String, Id>();
System.debug('FIRSTsubAccIdsByName='+subaccNames);   
           for (Vendor_Product__c subAcc : [select id, Name from Vendor_Product__c where Name in :subAccNames]) 
                   {
                      subAccIdsByName.put(subAcc.Name, subAcc.id);
System.debug('subAcc Name and ID=' + subAcc.Name +'Id=' + subAcc.id);
                   }

System.debug('SECONDsubAccIdsByName=' + subAccIdsByName);

           //For each position processed by the trigger, add a new  

           //Product_Affected_Entry__c record for the specified Products_Affected3__c.  

           //Note that Trigger.New is a list of all the new positions  

           //that are being created.  

           for (Policy_Profile__c newContract : Trigger.New) 
           {
              if (newContract.Products_Affected3__c != '[]') 
              {
                 // split out the multi-select picklist using a comma delimiter
System.debug('Products_Affected3__c ' + newContract.Products_Affected3__c);

                 String temp = newContract.Products_Affected3__c;
                 temp = temp.replace(']','');
                 temp = temp.replace('[','');
                 String[] all = temp.split(',');

                 for(String subsoncontract: all)
                 {

                    subsoncontract = subsoncontract.normalizeSpace();
System.debug('subsoncontract'+subsoncontract);
                    //for(String subsoncontract: newContract.Products_Affected3__c.split(',')){

                    Product_Affected_Entry__c ssoc = new Product_Affected_Entry__c(

                            //Name = subsoncontract,
                            Policy__c = newContract.Id,
                            Vendor__c = newContract.Vendor__c,
                            Vendor_Product__c = subAccIdsByName.get(subsoncontract), // GET THE SUB ACCOUNT ID BASED ON NAME
                            Policy_and_Product__c = newContract.Name + '~' + subAccIdsByName.get(subsoncontract)); 
                            //Contract_Start_Date__c = newContract.Contract_Start_Date__c,
                           // Contract_End_Date__c = newContract.Contract_End_Date__c,
                           // Logo_Usage_Allowed__c = 'Yes');

                    subs.add(ssoc);
                 }
              } 
           }

           upsert subs ;

        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: what data does products_affected3__c contain why are you checking if products_affected3__c ! = '[]'? are you trying to check if the products_affected3__c != null?

Comment: Rao - Yes, I'm checking to see if it's null. Products_Affected3__c contains the selections which were made from a picklist. The picklist choices are dynamically created based on other field choices and the choices are all names of other records. And I am attempting to automatically create a junction records between the current record and all of those choices by populating a lookup field in the newly created records with the record ID of the records which those choices represent. But only the lookup field of the first record produced is being populated.